# Save Last Fragment when click homebutton and back to app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-backstack

Sorry for my poor English.. but i have two problems and i cant go on.

### I have a app (Android) and i'm working with Fragments.

Problem:
 * I have the main activity and 3 fragments (to show other information's)

In the main activity i call the fragment and i put him in backstack.
addToBackStack(null) and i not add a fragment..the code is "replace".
always when i call a fragment i add in backstack.
And when i click in menu to show the fragment, show normally without problems.

BUT 
   When i press the "Android Home Button" to show the "Android home screen" and i click again in my app THE LAST fragment disappear.

When i click to show the recent applications in android and back to app, same thing... the last fragment disappear...

I read something to manage onResume, but i'm blocked on this.

PS: Always when i press HomeButton or Recent Applications, i see on debug the fragment call "onDestroy" and the getBackStackEntryCount() is 0.

Sorry i don't have code in this PC..but if someone help me with this..i will be very happy!.. after i will put the code here!

[HomeButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CBTe.jpg)

[RecentApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGfsc.png)

Comment: Could you please update your question with the relevant code?

Comment: I dont have the code in this moment..just when i came from the work. but i will write something and post it now

Comment: Sorry i cant put correctly the code.. but thinking in the problem... i cant see the last fragment when i click in device homebutton ou recent application list.. i put two images in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

I think the problem is this..